# Why I can't find A.N.T. Landscape in add-ons tab (Blender 2.80)

Tags: customization

Why I can't find A.N.T. Landscape in add-ons tab (Blender 2.80)

Answer (score 1):

Search for landscape. Then the addon should show up.

Community needs to be enabled.

[image]

Comment: maybe add the advise that the 'Community' toggle needs to be set, as A.N.T. landscape is a Community plugin, and won't show up if that toggle is deactivated

Comment: Community is enabled by default. But good hint. Updated.